# Fill window with iFrame and not show scrollbars?

Tags: html, css, iframe

How can I make my iframe fill the window and not display any scrollbars?

This works for IE6, I would like to get it to work for all browsers if possible:

```
<iframe name=iframe1 src="theSiteToShow.html"  width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="10" marginwidth="10"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizeIframe() {
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    height -= document.getElementById('frame').offsetTop;

    // not sure how to get this dynamically
    height -= 20; /* whatever you set your body bottom margin/padding to be */

    document.getElementById('frame').style.height = height +"px";

};
document.getElementById('frame').onload = resizeIframe;
window.onresize = resizeIframe;
</script>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should be able to do this using CSS only, without any need for javascript.  The following works for me in IE6+, Google Chrome and Safari:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
#iframe1 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>

<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" frameborder="0"  
     src="theSiteToShow.html"></iframe>
```

Your frame margins should be set in the body of `theSiteToShow.html`.

**UPDATE**
Following your comment, I used the following as a test page:

```
<html> 
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
#iframe1 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
<iframe id="iframe1" src="http://stackoverflow.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body> 
</html>
```

Tested in IE6+, Chrome, Safari and Firefox, it works just fine and fills the entire window.

Comment: The iframe won't fill the window. It will place itself at 0,0 in the top left hand corner and be at around 300x150px in size. What's missing? Feels like it should fill the window.

Comment: @Zolomon: My code works fine for me in IE, Firefox and Chrome.  Maybe you could copy the test code I wrote and use that as a base to build your own code from?

Comment: Thank you, your examples works! Don't know what was wrong with mine.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issues with the scroll bars as well as the No Context Menu showing up, even though all these elements had been disabled. After a few days of trying to solve them, I stumbled on this post, which helped a bit, but led me onto finding a post on flexible webplayers with three code examples. Here're the links:

http://virtualplayground.d2.pl/?p=367#comment-224

[Download package](http://virtualplayground.d2.pl/WP/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=5)

Use the index file if you want a blank sheet to work from, replace your existing code in your exported .html file (from Unity export), replace the 'unityObject.embedUnity' link with your own link to your .html file located on your server.

To embed the player in your page using an iframe add:

Lock and load.

Hope this helps.

^_^